# WHMCS - Add client name and email to Affiliates Page

Tags: php, whmcs, affiliate, whmcs-invoice-template

my clients need this information on the affiliate page, can you help me add this information by changing affiliates.tpl or some other way? Thanks.

**Informations:** Name and e-mail

Below is the code, I just want to add the information so that my affiliates know who they referred.
Thank you all for helping me, and I wish you a happy new year to all.

```
{if $inactive}

    {include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="danger" msg=$LANG.affiliatesdisabled textcenter=true}

{else}

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="affiliate-stat affiliate-stat-green alert-warning">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <span>{$vis[enter image description here][1]itors}</span>
                {$LANG.affiliatesclicks}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="affiliate-stat affiliate-stat-green alert-info">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                <span>{$signups}</span>
                {$LANG.affiliatessignups}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="affiliate-stat affiliate-stat-green alert-success">
                <i class="far fa-chart-bar"></i>
                <span>{$conversionrate}%</span>
                {$LANG.affiliatesconversionrate}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="affiliate-referral-link text-center">

        <h3>{$LANG.affiliatesreferallink}</h3>
        <span>{$referrallink}</span>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <table class="table table-striped table-rounded">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right">{$LANG.affiliatescommissionspending}:</td>
                    <td><strong>{$pendingcommissions}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right">{$LANG.affiliatescommissionsavailable}:</td>
                    <td><strong>{$balance}</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-right">{$LANG.affiliateswithdrawn}:</td>
                    <td><strong>{$withdrawn}</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    {if $withdrawrequestsent}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{$LANG.affiliateswithdrawalrequestsuccessful}</p>
        </div>
    {else}
        <p class="text-center">
            <a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?action=withdrawrequest" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"{if !$withdrawlevel} disabled="true"{/if}>
                <i class="fas fa-university"></i> {$LANG.affiliatesrequestwithdrawal}
            </a>
        </p>
        {if !$withdrawlevel}
            <p class="text-muted text-center">{lang key="affiliateWithdrawalSummary" amountForWithdrawal=$affiliatePayoutMinimum}</p>
        {/if}
    {/if}

    {include file="$template/includes/subheader.tpl" title=$LANG.affiliatesreferals}

    {include file="$template/includes/tablelist.tpl" tableName="AffiliatesList"}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function ()
        {
            var table = jQuery('#tableAffiliatesList').removeClass('hidden').DataTable();
            {if $orderby == 'regdate'}
                table.order(0, '{$sort}');
            {elseif $orderby == 'product'}
                table.order(1, '{$sort}');
            {elseif $orderby == 'amount'}
                table.order(2, '{$sort}');
            {elseif $orderby == 'status'}
                table.order(4, '{$sort}');
            {/if}
            table.draw();
            jQuery('#tableLoading').addClass('hidden');
        });
    </script>
    <div class="table-container clearfix">
        <table id="tableAffiliatesList" class="table table-list hidden">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>{$LANG.affiliatessignupdate}</th>
                    <th>{$LANG.orderproduct}</th>
                    <th>{$LANG.affiliatesamount}</th>
                    <th>{$LANG.affiliatescommission}</th>
                    <th>{$LANG.affiliatesstatus}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {foreach from=$referrals item=referral}
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td><span class="hidden">{$referral.datets}</span>{$referral.date}</td>
                    <td>{$referral.service}</td>
                    <td data-order="{$referral.amountnum}">{$referral.amountdesc}</td>
                    <td data-order="{$referral.commissionnum}">{$referral.commission}</td>
                    <td><span class='label status status-{$referral.rawstatus|strtolower}'>{$referral.status}</span></td>
                </tr>
            {/foreach}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center" id="tableLoading">
            <p><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> {$LANG.loading}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    {if $affiliatelinkscode}
        {include file="$template/includes/subheader.tpl" title=$LANG.affiliateslinktous}
        <div class="margin-bottom text-center">
            {$affiliatelinkscode}
        </div>
    {/if}

{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no personal information available about the customers to the affiliate.
If you *really* want to show this information, you could fetch all rows from the table 'tblaffiliatesaccounts' where 'affiliateid' is equal to the specific affiliate's ID.
In the column 'relid' you have the service ID of referred customer.

Then search for the relid in 'tblhosting' in the 'id' column and fetch the corresponding userid. You can use this userid to fetch details about the user.

I can't see why your affiliates need to know the name and email address of their signups and it might violate some laws depending on which country you're located in. In the EU, you can't just share personal details about your customers.